# `as.complex(-1)^(1/3)` gives positive real part

Tags: r, complex-numbers

I am having a problem with R.

```
> as.complex(-1)^(1/3)
[1] 0.5+0.8660254i
```

This is certainly wrong as the real part is positive. Can anyone tell me the cause and solution?

N.B. A similar thing happens when I use `polyroot(c(1,0,0,1))`.

Comment: Its the same reason that the square root of 4 can be +2 or -2, but `sqrt(4)` only returns 2.

Answer (score 4):

R is giving the correct result. In the complex plane -1 has three cube roots. One of these is -1 (or -1 + 0i in complex-number notation), but the other two are complex numbers with a positive real part. For example:

```
x1 = as.complex(-1)^(1/3)

x1
```

> ```
> [1] 0.5+0.8660254i
> ```

```
x1^3
```

> ```
> [1] -1+0i
> ```

This makes sense because the argument of `x1`, that is, its angle with the x-axis in the complex plane, is 60 degrees (run `Arg(x1)`) and its modulus, which is the distance from the origin, is unity (run `Mod(x1)`). Thus, cubing it rotates `x1` counterclockwise by 120 degrees, bringing it back to `-1+0i`.

The two other cube roots of -1 are found by successive 120 degree rotations of `x1` about the origin. They are:

```
x2 = -1 + 0i
x3 = Conj(x1) = 0.5-0.8660254i
```

If you cube them, you'll also recover `-1+0i`. The cube roots of -1 are a mirror image (if you reflect across the imaginary axis) of the cube roots of unity in the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I was just beaten in my reply. Anyway.

So, in doubt that (0.5+0.8660254i)^3 is -1. So, checking that the length of the vector of the polar representation:

```
> sqrt(0.5^2+0.8660254^2)
[1] 1
```

This sounds like right since 1^3 is still also the length of the vector of (-1 + 0i) in polar coordinates. Then the remaining question is if the angle of (0.5+0.8660254i) is at 60 (pi/3) degrees, such that when multiplying by 3 it is at the 180 (pi) of (-1+0i). Hm.

As vividly explained on https://www2.clarku.edu/~djoyce/complex/polar.html, the real and imaginary parts are the catheti of a triangle and the angle computes as the arc-tangent:

```
> atan(0.8660254/0.5)/pi
[1] 0.3333333
```

Since multiplying complex numbers sums the angles of their polar coordinates, the ^3 triples that fraction of pi, which then adds up to a full half circle.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that R computes `z^a` as `exp(a * log(z))`.

The value `exp(z)` is uniquely defined for any `z`, but there are many possible values to choose for `log(z)`. I suspect that for a complex number `z = r * exp(i * theta)` with `-pi < theta <= pi` and `r` a positive real, R sets `log(z) = log(r) + 1i * theta`.

This gives `(-1)^(1/3) = exp((1/3) * log(-1)) = exp(pi * 1i / 3) = 0.5+0.8660254i`.

If R chose a different value for the logarithm, for example if it set `log(-1) = 3 * pi * 1i`, then you would get instead

```
(-1)^(1/3) = exp(3 * pi * 1i / 3) = -1,
```

the answer you expected. Why doesn't R give you this value? Because then for the sake of consistency, `log(e^(theta * 1i))` would have to be defined as `1i * theta + 2 * pi * 1i` for `-pi < theta <= pi`.